# Modifying jQuery UI Datepicker behaviour

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, calendar

I'm trying to modify 2 elements on the jQuery UI datepicker.

1. Disable Mondays and Sundays
2. Disable the current date and dates in the past.

For context, it's so someone can select a future date for in-store collection.

I have the disable Monday + Sunday working

```
(function($) {
$(document).ready(function() {

   $("#after_order_notes_choose_a_collection").datepicker({
beforeShowDay: function(d)
  { return [!(d.getDay()==1||d.getDay()==0)] }
 
   });
  
}); })(jQuery);
```

The following script itself, doesn't seem to work as it should

```
(function($) {
$(document).ready(function() {$('').datepicker({ minDate: 0 });
})(jQuery);
```

and when I add it, it breaks the first one.

I've tried a range of variations of the 2nd one, but none have worked and all break the first one.

Wondering if anyone has any insight?

Answer (score 0):

You are very close!

Use the `minDate` property to help with disabling current (or past dates).

> From the API:
> **Number**: A number of days from today. For example 2 represents two days
> from today and -1 represents yesterday.

So based on that info, we can use 1 as "one day from today". Try the example below.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

   $("#after_order_notes_choose_a_collection").datepicker({
      minDate: 1,
      beforeShowDay: function(d)
        { return [!(d.getDay() < 2)] }
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

Date: <input id="after_order_notes_choose_a_collection">
```

API docs on the `minDate` (and other datepicker properties) can be found [here](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-minDate).